# 2012 R2 Server stopped allowing external connections overnight

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012, port, port-forwarding

I am using a 2012 R2 server that we use for remote desktop. Overnight, external connections suddently stopped working - no changes to the server, no reboots ( i have now the problem presented ).

When I run a tracert from the computer I am trying to connect with, it fails at 144.130.212.2 which seems to be a telstra NS.

Does anyone have any input, suggestions or ideas about what I can do to get our business back up and running? Many thanks. P.S ports are open according to nMap

Answer (score 1):

What exactly error do you get? Did you try connecting to the server using its IP address or its host name? You say the **external** connectivity is failing - can you connect over the server's private IP?

As the problem may lie in a firewall device before the server, confirm connectivity to the server by this PowerShell cmdlet, before proceeding further (use your actual RDP port):

Test-NetConnection -Computername [IP address] -port *3389*

What you describe can also be caused by a hung terminal service (RDS). **Only** if you have any access to the server (iLo, iDRAC, console, RDP, VNC, whatever), you can try restarting the service using the Services Control or directly via the console:

**for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('wmic service where "name=\"termservice\" get processid" /format:list') do @wmic process where processid='%i' terminate&net start termservice**

Please note that the approach is sending all commands **at once**, in case you are connected over RDP. This ensures the service will come back online without cutting off your access.

Lastly - try connecting to the server in admin mode with:

mstsc /admin /v:IP